# MySQL/PHP: How to calculate the average of a certain column using a JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have one `items` table with columns: `id`, `name`, `category` and one `ratings` table with columns: `id`, `item`, `rating`.

How do I calculate the average rating for each item?

I'd like to have a php array returned with:

```
[id] => item.id
[name] => item.name
[rating] => average rating
```

This is my PHP function so far:

```
function getTopRatings($category) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT item, rating, items.id, items.name FROM ratings INNER JOIN items ON ratings.item=items.id WHERE category = '" . $category . "'";
    $pdo->query($sql);
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        $ratings[] = array(
            "itemid" => $row['id'],
            "name" => $row['name'],
            "rating" => ?
        );
    }
    Database::disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the SQL `AVG()` function, no need to do it in PHP. You also need to  `GROUP BY` the item's ID, otherwise you'd get the average for every item:

```
SELECT item, AVG(rating) as rating, items.id, items.name FROM ratings INNER JOIN items ON ratings.item=items.id WHERE category = '" . $category . "' GROUP BY items.id;
```

Now, the `rating` field in your result is the average for every item.

You should read up on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Right now, your query is vulnerable to SQL injections.